# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when keyboard appears

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

When I click a text field into my app screen and the keyboard is showing up xcode debugger shows this error:

```
[mainViewController keyboardWasShown]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5867ac0
```

In the viewDidLoad method of the mainViewController I'm calling the registerForKeyboardNotifications method like that:

**[self registerForKeyboardNotifications];**

Here's its implementation (in mainViewController.m):

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{

}
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you copy and paste that code directly from your source? You appear to be registering a notification with the selector `keyboardWasShown:` but the exception message mentions a `keyboardWasShown` selector (the colon at the end is important).

Comment: Right, I think it could be the issue...I'm testing it right now!

Comment: can you make it a reply so that I can vote for you ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the notification selector has the colon at the end; this is important, `keyboardWasShown` and `keyboardWasShown:` are different selectors.